# Lego Gray, green, and black parts. What set would these parts belong to?

Tags: set-identification

Lego Gray, green, and black parts.  What set would these parts belong to?
Could you help me identify the set that they go to?[image]

Answer (score 2):

You've got four pieces of part [30246 Panel 3 x 4 x 6 Turret Wall with Window, in light bluish gray](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=30246#C=86).

It's a relatively rare part - only appears in 18 sets, and only 2 of those sets have 4 or more of it. The green roof slopes tell me it's [Bowser's Castle Boss Battle](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=71369-1).

[image]