# I have these Legos that are reds, browns, and grays. Trying to find the set

Tags: set-identification

I have these Legos that are reds, browns, and grays.  Trying to find the set.
What set would they go to?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Lego Gray, green, and black parts. What set would these parts belong to?](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/18017/lego-gray-green-and-black-parts-what-set-would-these-parts-belong-to)

Comment: Turns out it's not a duplicate - I missed the 3x3 round tiles.

Answer (score 2):

Base on 3 parts that identified:

- 8x8 plate w/ 4 feet (66790) in Red
- 4x4 plate w/ 4 feet (66792) in Dark Orange
- And an 3x3 round tile (67095) in LBG

If finding all 3 identified parts on BL results.

This refers to set # [71380: Master Your Adventure](https://brickset.com/sets/71380-1/Master-Your-Adventure)

[image]